# Ubuntu symbolic link the content of a folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

I have two folders such as

```
nonserved/
    folder1/
    folder2/
```

and a served folder via Apache

```
media/
    js/
    css/
    img/
```

In the end, I want to include/append contents of /nonserved to /media so that www.mysite.com/media will be as such:

```
/media
    /js
    /css
    /img
    /folder1
    /folder2
```

I am running Ubuntu Server, I am up for either apache config or symbolic link based answer :) Plus nonserved folder is rather dynamic thus manual symbolic linking to each folder is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

```
Alias /media/folder1/ nonserved/folder1/
Alias /media/folder2/ nonserved/folder2/

<Directory nonserved/>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```